# Why does onOpen always starts with my userMenu an not with my adminMenu?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing from germany - so I hope you can understand my writings.

With the following code I try to open an e-mail depending menu while the file is openened.
But it should open a user e-mail depending menu (one for admin, one for the user).

this way I get only the user menu, even when I use the admin email adress in google.

So... where is my mistake?

Greetings from germany
Thorsten

```
function onOpen(e) {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser();
  var admin1Email = 't.mahlfeldt@pro-immoservice.de';

  if (userEmail == admin1Email){
  ui.createMenu('menu Admin')
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Tools')
.
.
.
  }else if (userEmail != admin1Email){ 
  ui.createMenu('menu User')
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('User')
```

Comment: Can you please specify `even when I use the admin email adress in google`? What is your active account when you open the spreadsheet? Is it 't.mahlfeldt@pro-immoservice.de'? Is 't.mahlfeldt@pro-immoservice.de' your GSuite account?

Comment: Yes, "t.mahlfeldt@pro-immoservice.de" is always my active account, when I work with google spreadsheet.

Comment: I recommend you to add to your code before the `if` statement the line `Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser());` for troubleshooting.

Comment: I tried it before and the log gave me 't.mahlfeldt@pro-immoservice.de' back - that's why Im a little bit helpless...

Comment: Does anybody else have the same spreadsheet open simultaneously to you?

Comment: No, I tried it if it was only opened by me and another time opened by different people - same result

Comment: I cannot not reproduce your problem. I cannot only recommend you to implement logs before entering the `if` statement and inside. And make sure that you do not have the document opened a second time somewhere in the background or by another user.

Comment: Ok, thanks so far. I hope I find the problem with the help of the logs. :-)